# BIRT report, EXPORT to PDF by detault.?

Tags: java, pdf, reporting-services, pdf-generation, birt

i am trying to make default select option for Export to Excel/PDF

As shown in image
1.Excel> only auto radio button is selected (rest we can't select)
2. same manner i want PDF> only actual size should select (rest we can't select)

how can i achieve that?[image: EXCEL]

.
.
.
.
.
.
..
[image: PDF]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto -->**\webcontent\birt\pages\dialog\ExportReportDialogFragment.jsp** of your war file and you can customize of your own display option based upon the selection in the export format.